# Loading data from JSON using Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I had code like this:

```
JBenchApp.controller('CaseListCtrl', ['$scope',
  function ($scope) {
      // Case list stuff here
      $scope.cases = [
          {
              'number': '30-2013-0069378-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Baumgartner - Probate',
              'sequence': '',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Petition for Final Distribution',
              'event2': ''
          },
          {
              'number': '30-2013-00649408-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Dupaquier - Probate',
              'sequence': '',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Petition - Other',
              'event2': ''
          },
          {
              'number': '30-2011-00510275-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Baker - Conservatorship',
              'sequence': '',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Accounting',
              'event2': 'Review Hearing'
          },
          {
              'number': '30-2010-00334622-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Montero - Minors Compromise',
              'sequence': '',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Review Hearing',
              'event2': ''
          },
          {
              'number': '30-2011-005260282-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Reed - Conservatorship',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Petition - Other',
              'event2': ''
          }
      ];

      $scope.departments = [
          {
              'dept': '1'
          },
          {
              'dept': '1A'
          },
          {
              'dept': '2'
          },
          {
              'dept': '2A',
          },
          {
              'dept': '2B'
          },
          {
              'dept': '2C'
          },
          {
              'dept': '2D'
          },
          {
              'dept': '3'
          },
          {
              'dept': '4'
          },
          {
              'dept': '5'
          },
          {
              'dept': '6'
          },
          {
              'dept': '7'
          },
          {
              'dept': '8'
          },
          {
              'dept': '9'
          },
          {
              'dept': '11'
          },
          {
              'dept': '12'
          },
          {
              'dept': '13'
          },
          {
              'dept': '14'
          },
          {
              'dept': '15'
          },
          {
              'dept': '16'
          },
          {
              'dept': '17'
          },
          {
              'dept': '18'
          },
          {
              'dept': '19'
          },
          {
              'dept': '20'
          },
          {
              'dept': '21'
          },
          {
              'dept': '22'
          },
          {
              'dept': '23'
          }
      ];


  }]);
```

and I wanted to move the data to an external file. I now have a cases.js file (.json won't work on my local machine) that has the data like this:

```
[
          {
              'number': '30-2013-0069378-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Baumgartner - Probate',
              'sequence': '',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Petition for Final Distribution',
              'event2': ''
          },
          {
              'number': '30-2013-00649408-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Dupaquier - Probate',
              'sequence': '',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Petition - Other',
              'event2': ''
          },
          {
              'number': '30-2011-00510275-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Baker - Conservatorship',
              'sequence': '',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Accounting',
              'event2': 'Review Hearing'
          },
          {
              'number': '30-2010-00334622-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Montero - Minors Compromise',
              'sequence': '',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Review Hearing',
              'event2': ''
          },
          {
              'number': '30-2011-005260282-PR-PL-CJC',
              'title': 'Reed - Conservatorship',
              'time': '9:00 am',
              'event': 'Petition - Other',
              'event2': ''
          }
];
```

I have changed my code as follows:

```
JBenchApp.controller('CaseListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function ($scope, $http) {
      // Case list stuff here
      $http.get('json/cases.js').success(function (response) {
          $scope.cases = response;
      });

      $scope.departments = [
          {
              'dept': '1'
          },
          {
              'dept': '1A'
          },
          {
              'dept': '2'
          },
          {
              'dept': '2A',
          },
          {
              'dept': '2B'
          },
          {
              'dept': '2C'
          },
          {
              'dept': '2D'
          },
          {
              'dept': '3'
          },
          {
              'dept': '4'
          },
          {
              'dept': '5'
          },
          {
              'dept': '6'
          },
          {
              'dept': '7'
          },
          {
              'dept': '8'
          },
          {
              'dept': '9'
          },
          {
              'dept': '11'
          },
          {
              'dept': '12'
          },
          {
              'dept': '13'
          },
          {
              'dept': '14'
          },
          {
              'dept': '15'
          },
          {
              'dept': '16'
          },
          {
              'dept': '17'
          },
          {
              'dept': '18'
          },
          {
              'dept': '19'
          },
          {
              'dept': '20'
          },
          {
              'dept': '21'
          },
          {
              'dept': '22'
          },
          {
              'dept': '23'
          }
      ];


  }]);
```

My partial looks like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
    <div class="col-sm-12 calselectrow">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calicon"></span>
        <input type="text" id="calpick" ng-model="date"  jdatepicker />
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary flat-edge">>></a>
        <span class="bluedept">Department:</span>
        <select class="selectpicker deptpicker" selectpicker ng-controller="CaseListCtrl">
            <option ng-repeat="department in departments">{{department.dept}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
    <div ng-controller="CaseListCtrl">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 caselist" ng-repeat-start="case in cases track by $index">
            <div class="sequence">
                <input type=text class="seq-box" size="1" value="{{case.sequence}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="casetitle">
                <a href="/case/{{case.number}}" class="caselink">{{case.number}}</a>
                <a href="/case/{{case.number}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="/case/{{case.number}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                </a>
                {{case.title}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 caselist-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="hearing-time">{{case.time}}</div>
                <div class="hearing-title">{{case.event}}</div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat-end></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i run this I get a bunch of rows with no data at all. If I take out the "track by $index" I get an error about duplicate key. How can I make this work so it displays my data?

Answer (score 0):

This code will not be interpreted as javascript as this a security issue. you will need to use jsonp or return this data as json in the body of the response.

Try this:

```
$http({method: 'JSONP', url:<your url> + ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK})
```

and change your response to return:

```
JSON_CALLBACK ([your array]);
```

Comment: I had to add a MIME type for the .JSON, but I am still getting the same results. I just get a bunch of rows with no data at all. If I take out the track by $index I get an error about a duplicate key. This works when the line of code is just $scope.cases = (and the JSON data right here) so I am not sure what the issue really is. Help?

Comment: does $scope.cases populated correctly when the get is done?

Comment: Not that I can see...what happens is the ng-repeat goes through the motions and lists out a bunch of rows of what should be data, but is empty

Comment: can you try and console.log($scope.cases) and see what returns from the get call?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the JSON was not valid. I was using single quotes when I should have used double quotes. I was also ending the file with a semi-colon and that has to be omitted. When I do that it works perfectly.